# "firebase.database.ref is not a function" when connecting to Firebase using JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting a weird error when trying to connect a web page to firebase realtime database. I get the error,

> Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database.ref is not a function.

The error points to the below line of code

```
const db = firebase.database.ref();
```

I copied the script from my firebase project and I added the imports. For the initialisation I have removed the apiKey etc for the question.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.0/firebase-app.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.0/firebase- 
database.js"></script>

<script>
// Initialize Firebase
const config = {
          apiKey: "",
          authDomain: "",
          databaseURL: "",
          projectId: "",
          storageBucket: "",
          messagingSenderId: ""
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script>
    const db = firebase.database.ref();
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do

```
const db = firebase.database().ref();
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database

---

Note that you could maybe rename your variable to `rootRef` instead of `db`, and use `db` for `firebase.database()`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if i can be of much use without seeing the entire code , (not talking about the firebase apikeys and stuff) but i came accross this issue couple of weeks back while i was working with React-Native . Now though they dont function the same way the error might be because you are missing few libraries or you are not using the latest versions of them . The error details are not as friendly as they seem .
I fixed this issue with installing the latest libraries - headsup sometimes even when u do install them they tend to install with errors so best guess is to "delete the installed packges first" and then"reinistall" .
Also add the following

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>.
```

After that , i remember i had to sometimes Database and Auth pieces need to be required separately since they aren't bundled when including Firebase in this way.So i fixed it usng a the below code ,

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/database');
```

Last but not least you are also missing the function () in your code , but im not sure f that alone is the issue . so just add

`const db = firebase.database().ref();`.

I do have a feeling this could fix it alone , but sometimes it might need all the packages above as well . Let me know how it goes . Good luck . Connecting can be a hasle sometimes for all not just you.

Comment: Hi, I already have it solved! Thanks